# Is it possible for an Azure App Service to connect to an On-Premises Database using a Site to Site VPN?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-vpn

I have setup an Site-to-Site VPN connection using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal). I have been researching ways to for my App Service to connect to an on-premises database using this VPN tunnel however I only found information from Point-To-Site and Hybrid Connections.  I was wondering if it is possible to achieve this with a Site-to-Site VPN connection.

I am trying to query data from an on-premises database from a web application.

Comment: This really should be posted to ServerFault, not Stack Overflow. Also, as written, this really doesn't need the [tag:database] tag, since (as written) it has nothing to do with any database.

Answer (score 0):

Vnet intergation is the component you need for app service to connect with VNet/S2S VPN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration#access-on-premises-resources

Comment: Should the P2S be on the save VNet as the S2S?  Or should they be different but connected through the connections section in the VNet settings (VNet to VNet connection).